# Ruby & Postgresql LIKE for both string and decimal

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have a search query that worked in sqllite, but when I migrated to postgres it doesn't work anymore. I can understand the error, which is below, just not sure how to fix it.. This is the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does 
not exist: numeric ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ...ustomers".* FROM "customers" WHERE (credit_amount LIKE '%tri...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might 
need to add explicit type casts.
```

Which makes sense, I'm just not sure what to do I looked up `CAST` to cast my decimal into a string, but I don't think that's right. Here is the search:

```
search_term = "%#{params["search"]}%"
customers = Customer.where('credit_amount LIKE :search 
                      OR email LIKE :search 
                      OR first_name LIKE :search 
                      OR last_name LIKE :search
                      OR pending_credit_amount LIKE :search                          
                      OR tags LIKE :search', search: 
search_term).order(first_name: params["order"])
```

`credit` and `pending_credit` are decimals with the rest being strings.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just... Replace `credit_amount LIKE` with `credit_amount =`?!

Comment: man.. because I can't see the forest for the trees! geez.. I'm pretty sure that's perfect..

Comment: shoot, no.. it doesn't like the type.. if I enter in a string and its looking for an integer

Comment: Ahh wait hang on, this is because you're doing `"%#{params["search"]}%"`... Yeah, I think you'd need to do a text cast then, unless you want to get clever with some crazy [Arel table](https://coderwall.com/p/qtgvdq/using-arel_table-for-ilike-yes-even-with-integers) code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is that credit_amount in customers table is an integer. If so, you have to cast credit_amount to text in order to compare it to search parameter. I'd do like this:

```
search_term = "%#{params["search"]}%"
customers = Customer.where('credit_amount::text LIKE :search 
                  OR email LIKE :search 
                  OR first_name LIKE :search 
                  OR last_name LIKE :search
                  OR pending_credit_amount LIKE :search                          
                  OR tags LIKE :search', 
                  search: search_term).order(first_name: params["order"])
```

Same with other non-text columns, like "pending_credit_amount" column I guess.

Comment: that was what I was looking for! perfecto!